# Eclipse CDT conditional compilation?

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I have a line of code that Eclipse CDT (Oxygen) code fails to recognise. I'm pretty sure the code is perfectly fine. It compiles OK but I still like project without red squiggles on them.

How can I tell Eclipse ignore this line? I imagine I would enclose it in conditional compilation directives that only affect code checking but not normal compilation. Something like this:

```
#ifdef _ECLIPSE_CODE_CHECKER
    my_bad_code();
#endif
```

But I cannot find any such macro predefined by Eclipse.

It would be even better to make the code checker simply accept this line.

Here's the smallish example:

```
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/support/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
namespace bpt = boost::posix_time;


int main()
{
  logging::add_file_log(
   logging::keywords::file_name ="file.log",
   logging::keywords::format =
    (expr::stream << expr::format_date_time<bpt::ptime >("T:", "%H:%M:%S") << expr::smessage));    
}
```

Eclipse complains about `add_file_log` having invalid arguments. Removing `format_date_time` makes the error go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro you're looking for exists and is called `__CDT_PARSER__`:

```
#ifdef __CDT_PARSER__
    my_bad_code();
#endif
```

As for Eclipse's code checker accepting the line, I would encourage you to [file a CDT bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT).